# How to use spark.DataFrameReader from Foundry Transforms

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a file with non-classic formatting so I need to use the `spark.DataFrameReader` (`spark.read.csv`) on the raw file directly so that I can set the appropriate parsing configurations.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your interest using DataFrameReader itself or just parse CSVs?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to follow the methodology over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997667/how-do-i-parse-large-compressed-csv-files-in-foundry).  Strongly recommend using unit test based methods to iterate on your code to recover the file contents.

Your compute function code will look like:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Output, Input
from transforms.verbs.dataframes import union_many


def read_files(spark_session, paths):
    parsed_dfs = []
    for file_name in paths:
        parsed_df = spark_session.read.option("header", "true").csv(file_name)
        parsed_dfs += [parsed_df]
    output_df = union_many(*parsed_dfs)
    return output_df


@transform(
    the_output=Output("ri.foundry.main.dataset.my-awesome-output"),
    the_input=Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.my-awesome-input"),
)
def my_compute_function(the_input, the_output, ctx):
    session = ctx.spark_session
    input_filesystem = the_input.filesystem()
    hadoop_path = input_filesystem.hadoop_path
    files = input_filesystem.ls('**/*.csv.gz').map(lambda file_name: hadoop_path + file_name)
    output_df = read_files(session, files)
    the_output.write_dataframe(output_df)
```