# In Palantir Foundry how do I parse a very large csv file with OOMing the driver or executor?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

Similar to [How do I parse large compressed csv files in Foundry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997667/how-do-i-parse-large-compressed-csv-files-in-foundry) but without the file being compressed, a system generated (>10GB) csv file which needs to be parsed as a Foundry Dataset.

A dataset this size normally causes the driver to OOM, so how can I parse this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the filesystem, you can read the file and yield a rowwise operation to split on each seperator (`,`) in this case.

```
df = raw_dataset
fs = df.filesystem()
def process_file(fl):
    with fs.open("data_pull.csv", "r") as f:
        header = [x.strip() for x in f.readline().split(",")]
        Log = Row(*header)
        for i in f:
            yield Log(*i.split(","))
rdd = fs.files().rdd
rdd = rdd.flatMap(process_file)
df = rdd.toDF()
```